# Error when installing haskell-platform from source

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I need to install from source files the haskell platform so as indicated in the instructions installed cabal, ghc and other libraries for Ubuntu that are needed.

When I try to install the haskell platform with the command:

```
./platform.sh /home/myuser/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64-unknown-linux-deb7.tar.bz2 -j 3
```

I get the following error:

```
***
*** Building hptool
***
Building hptool-0.1...
Preprocessing executable 'hptool' for hptool-0.1...
***
*** Running hptool
***
Error when running Shake build system:
* 3
Error, file does not exist and no rule available:
  3
```

and I don't find anyone with same error. The haskell platform version that I have downloaded is haskell-platform-7.10.2-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `./platform.sh` script you can't pass a build option like `-j 3`.

Try building and running hptool manually like this:

```
cd hptool
cabal sandbox init
cabal install -j3

cd ..
./hptool/.cabal-sandbox/bin/hptool PATH-TO-GHC-BINDIST SHAKE-TARGET
```

Run hptool with no arguments to get a list of valid values for SHAKE-TARGET.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. Now I get another error: user error (Development.Shake.command_, system command failed
Command: cabal unpack hscolour-1.23
Current directory: /home/yabir/haskell/haskell-platform/build/package/hscolour-1.23
cabal: createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory))
Can you help me?

Comment: You need the hscolour command in your PATH. Perhaps `cabal install hscolour`?

Comment: Btw - why are you building the Haskell Platform? You can download a precompiled version for Linux, OS X and Windows - that's what most people do.